# fsck on ext4 resulted in file corruption

Tags: filesystem, ext4, fsck

I had to hard reboot my machine and I had a file system corruption. I have tried to run `fsck` on the partition from live CD. However my partition is `ext4` and I understand that `fsck` defaults to `ext2` which happened in my case of an old boot-repair disk. Now my file system is further corrupted.

How to fix this problem and recover my Ubuntu 10.04 back?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you do not touch the disk any more.

You can however try to recover your files yourself with harddrive forensics analysis tools,
just download a backtrack livecd and recover files to a harddrive connected via usb.

Here you can download Backtrack: http://www.backtrack-linux.org/downloads/

If there are important files on the disk, then take it to a professional in recovering harddrives. Your money will be worth it.